# Spring cloud data flow Dashboard

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I have local scdf running 1.5.2 release
I am able to access the task UI via http://localhost:9393/dashboard/
I am able to create a timetask task. 
However on the top tabs I am not seeing anyway to schedule it, as mentioned here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#dashboard-tasks

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're going to the "current" version of the Docs. The current version always points to the latest GA release, which is currently at v1.6. To access v1.5.2, you'd have to use that [version of the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#dashboard-tasks), and we link the release-specific docs from the project site for convenience.

Task scheduling is a new feature and it was added as part of [v1.6](https://content.pivotal.io/pivotal-blog/spring-cloud-data-flow-1-6-is-ga-pcf-scheduler-integration-kubernetes-1-10-and-spring-boot-2-0-compatibility-ci-cd-improvements-and-more). Also, explicitly, it is supported *only* for the Cloud Foundry implementation of SCDF. Kubernetes implementation is targeted in the next release.

We do not have a local-server implementation yet. That's an area we are hoping to explore in the future.

Comment: Ok makes sense. Thanks